# Xamarin rest web service doesn't deserialize

Tags: c#, json, rest, xamarin

I want to use rest with get method. My code is below;

```
public class RegisterPage : ContentPage
{
    Label label, l4, label2;
    public RegisterPage()
    {
        Button btn = new Button
        {
            Text = "register"
        };

        btn.Clicked += Btn_Clicked;
        label = new Label();
        l4 = new Label();
        label2 = new Label();



        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = {
                btn,
                label,
                l4,
                label2
            }
        };
    }

    private async void Btn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(Constants.API_KEY_HEADER_KEY, Constants.API_KEY);
        string URL = Constants.URL;

        var response = await client.GetAsync(URL);

        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.Result>(content);


        label.Text = result.Success.ToString();


        l4.Text = result.Error.ToString();
        label2.Text = ((RegisteredDevice)result.Retval).Clientuuid + " - " + ((RegisteredDevice)result.Retval).Deviceuuid;
    }
}
```

The url is working good. And my content value has json string. But the serialization is not working.

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);
This code doesn't deserilize.

My model is;

```
public class Result
{
    private object retval = null;
    private bool success = false;
    private Error error = null;


    internal Error Error
    {
        get { return error; }
        set { error = value; }
    }

    public bool Success
    {
        get { return success; }
        set { success = value; }
    }

    public object Retval
    {
        get { return retval; }
        set { retval = value; }
    }
}
```

Json:

```
{  
   "result":{  
      "retail":{  
         "@xsi.type":"registeredDevice",
         "clientuuid":"28asgargb-acfe‌​-41dfgsdg51",
         "deviceuuid":123456
      },
      "success":true
   }
}
```

Comment: What does your JSON content look like?

Comment: {"result":{"retval":{"@xsi.type":"registeredDevice","clientuuid":"28asgargb-acfe-41dfgsdg51","deviceuuid":123456},"success":true}} @SushiHangover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem comes from :

```
private object retval = null;
```

So for me the best way to construct serialization objects in C# is to use this web site :

http://json2csharp.com/

This will tell you if your json is correct and he will generate the classes you need for you, here the classes generated by json2csharp

```
public class Retail
{
    public string __invalid_name__@xsi.type { get; set; }
    public string clientuuid { get; set; }
    public int deviceuuid { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public Retail retail { get; set; }
    public bool success { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Result result { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it is working perfectely. Thank you again